# 'redirect_url_mismatch' for some users in django-allauth (Google Login)

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, google-signin

I am using django-allauth for login with google in production server after testing in localhost. Its working fine for some users but some users are complaining that during login it gives this error 'redirect_url_mismatch'.
Is there anything related with http or https? The url is not 'https', its 'http'. 
This is the link which is used for login.
[Event Registration](http://horizonbcrec.in/accounts/google/login/?process=login)

Sorry if i asked a silly question but i am facing this problem and didn't able to find any way to solve this problem. Please give some suggesstions.